# Is there a way to run a Java interpreter/console in Windows?

Tags: java

In Firebug or Chrome, you can open a "Console" window and instantly start typing JavaScript expressions, and it immediately shows you the results of those expressions. This is extremely useful for people who learn best by doing. Is there something similar for executing Java? I realize Java is a compiled language, which is why I'm not sure.

(I believe Java already has a built in "console," but that isn't really what I'm describing here, as far as I know.)

Comment: have a look at this so question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958806/javas-interactive-shell-like-ipython

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, it's called BeanShell.

See http://www.beanshell.org/intro.html